# Adding a list item to an unordered list

Tags: jquery, list

I need to add an item  to the list:

```
<body>
<ul id="ulBack">
   <li><img src="bridges/01.png"/></li>
   <li><img src="bridges/02.jpg"/></li>
   <li><img src="bridges/03.jpg"/></li>
</ul>

<script>
jQuery('#ulBack').append('<li><img src="bridges/04.jpg"/></li>');

var list = $('#ulBack li');
alert (list.length);
</script>
</body>
```

Should be `4`, but the result is still `3`.

Comment: it is a typo or are you missing the <script> tags?

Comment: Nope, [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/SN9r4/).

Comment: Is the script after the HTML list ? This should work fine if you have the proper script element.

Comment: try to provide a jsfiddle and see the magic, ya, it works... Problem comes from somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you loaded jQuery?

If so, have you included your script in $(document).ready() ?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#ulBack').append('<li><img src="bridges/04.jpg"/></li>');

  var list = $('#ulBack li');
  alert (list.length);
 });
<script>
```

If not, you're probably trying to do this before the DOM is ready, and possibly your `<ul>` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: `DOM Ready handler` is not necessary in this case as the script is after the `HTML` .. Also the OP says that the length is 3 .. So jQuery was loaded properly

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work fine:

```
var myLi = $("<li><img src='bridges/04.jpg'/></li>");

myLi.appendTo($("#ulBack"));
```

:)

Comment: I think that it's _"jQuery('#ulBack').append('<li><img src="bridges/04.jpg"/></li>');"_ should be _"jQuery('#ulBack').append(**$(**'<li><img src="bridges/04.jpg"/></li>'**)**);"_

Comment: You can always append a string or a jQuery object. It does not matter

Comment: Thanks a lot to all. Solved. My mistake with script tags

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, i tried it out, my best guess is that you forgot to add the jquery library to your code, cause this works without problems:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>append test</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <ul id="ulBack">
           <li><img src="bridges/01.png"/></li>
           <li><img src="bridges/02.jpg"/></li>
           <li><img src="bridges/03.jpg"/></li>
        </ul>

        <script>
            jQuery('#ulBack').append('<li><img src="bridges/04.jpg"/></li>');

            var list = $('#ulBack li');
            alert (list.length);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```